# How to prevent Ionic modal from hidding

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I catch `modal.hidden` event, and do some check on it. When the check is `false`, I want to prevent the modal from hiding. I use `e.preventDefault()`. But it doesn't work.

My code & [CodePen](http://codepen.io/fenglu09/pen/oXErrN):

```
$scope.$on('modal.hidden', function(event) {
    var isPassed = false;
    // do some check
    if (isPassed == false) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `backdropClickToClose` and `hardwareBackButtonClose` option when setting up the modal and also hide the back button. This will prevent the modal from being closed:

```
// Load the modal from the given template URL
$scope.modal = {};
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    backdropClickToClose: false,
    hardwareBackButtonClose: false
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});
```

You can then do some check and set those values to `true` again, and also show the back button. This will still be user friendly and the user can close the modal in a proper way.

```
function checkSomething(){
    // The timeout is only to demonstrate, do your check here
    $timeout(function(){
      console.log("Now user can close modal")
      $scope.isPassed = true;
      $scope.modal.backdropClickToClose = true;
      $scope.modal.hardwareBackButtonClose = true;
    }, 3000)
}
```

Updated codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLXZGB)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in android platform, users have got used to use hardware back button to return. I think forbid it will bring a bad user experience.

Comment: hi, I meet another problem.  If I set `hardwareBackButtonClose: false` when init the modal, I can't close the modal by clicking hardware back button even I have set  `$scope.modal.hardwareBackButtonClose = true`

Comment: I found that change the value of `hardwareBackButtonClose` doesn't work if the modal has shown.  I solved my problem by another approach. Set the properties `backdropClickToClose` and `hardwareBackButtonClose` to false before the `modal.show()`. And then register my own back function to handle hardware back button.  Thanks for your help.